# Getting Errors After Moving Springboot Application to a Different Directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, directory

I have fully working Springboot application project in my Downloads directory but when i moved this project to a different directory for example : C:/User/Documents folder its still running but giving me visual errors. [it shows the classes are not imported even though they are and application is still running fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCrVQ.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bmuy.png

Im sure what's the reason is.
PS: Im using git. as version control for this project not sure if it is because I initialized the git when this project was in Downloads folder.

If someone knows the solution please let me know.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to:

1. Close IntelliJ
2. In your file explorer/finder, go to the directory your project is in now
3. Delete the `.idea`, `.mvn` and `target` folders
4. Open Idea again and just open the project from the folder again

Likely Idea is just confused.

**Update**: for Gradle, in step 3, look for `build` and `.gradle` folders.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted .idea and target then rebuilt the project, now its all good

Comment: Glad it worked out. IDEA can be finicky sometimes when it comes to project state so this and "invalidating caches" are my goto. Marking the question answered would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: I was just looking at this answer as it was edited. What are the chances?